# Save browser interpretation of a given URL as a single file or reduced directory

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I have a webserver which is used for development purposes, and as such I made it password protected via Apache.  In addition, the application utilizes serverside authentication.  Every now and then, I wish to share a page with someone, yet don't wish to give them the usernames/passwords of both Apache and the application.

Instead, I wish to give only the files required for a given instance of a browsers view the the website.  This should include HTML, JS, CSS,images, etc.

My purpose to do so is several fold.

One, as stated, the Apache directory and application is password protected, and I would rather not give out passwords.

Second, I don't wish to burden someone who is not responsible for server code and sql with a bunch of fluff.

Lastly, given out a static instance allows the underlining HTML to be better compared before and after.

How could this be best accomplished?

Thank you

Comment: Use .htaccess and .htpasswd to create a username and password for the user. You can also create an account for yourself so you can keep your credentials private. You can add and revoke access as necessary to the directory you wish.

Comment: I would rather then not access the actual server, and not be able enter data in forms/etc, but just see the rendered HTML.

Comment: @BigChris.  Sorry, didn't say so in my original post, but the application also is password protected in addition to the directory using .htpasswd.  I wish to logon myself so I am past both layers of protection, and copy the rendered HTML with application links to JS/CSS/etc, package that output, and either email it or save it in an unprotected space.

Comment: It seems you want the client to be able to make changes to the documents... You'll have no other choice but to release the entire site code to them... I see no point in protecting the content, just send them a zip of the source files but make sure the files are linked by relative URLs... Or have we missed something?

Comment: @BigChris  I just want to save what the client sees.  I wish to send someone ideally a zip file which has a file called index.html (or whatever) which is the HTML viewed by the browser, and maybe some directory structure that mimics the html root, but only contains files which were linked to by the aforementioned html file.  Alternatively, maybe some all-in-one file which includes all the linked resources? Someone could then use this to "see" exactly what I saw.  I don't want to send them a bunch of PHP/ASP/etc and SQL code used to generate the content seen by the browser.

Comment: The problem is your content is dynamic (from database) so you won't be able to send them a "series" of pages - for obvious reasons. The only option you have is to open the site on your own computer and "save page as" through your browser (send zip). Alternatively you could mock up a duplicate of their site but only using static HTML pages so you could have some working navigation. Extra work, yes, but you've made a developer faux pas by not agreeing a final design before developing your database and functionality.

Comment: Agree design comes before DB!  Have a design but wanted to add an extra feature.  I am okay with the JS/CSS side, but others are better and faster assuming I could give someone a starting point and easily integrate changes.  I don't care about navigation, but wanted to just present a single page to document all client script (obviously ajax won't work).

Comment: PS.  One of the reasons I want a static HTML file of a given server rendering is it makes it WAY easier to determine what the designer wants changes.  If we both take our own server rendered snapshot, 99% of the witnessed changes will be DB driven.

Comment: See this question was closed.  Strongly disagree that it should have been on the basis of being optioned based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a PDF file created from the page be acceptable, if the other person only needs to see what the page looks like, but won't be taking any action on the page? If so, there are lots of applications that you could use on one of your systems to "print" the page to a PDF file. You could then email the PDF file or make it available through some service, e.g., Google Drive, Dropbox, etc., that allows you to share files with others.

Another alternative would be "clip" the contents of the page using a service such as [Evernote](https://evernote.com) and share the page with them through that service, so they aren't accessing your development server, yet should see the page as you saw it. If the person doesn't have an Evernote account, you can use the "Share a public link (URL) to a note" instructions at *[Share Notes](https://evernote.com/contact/support/kb/#!/article/24973036)*. You could also do something similar through another webpage archiving service, [Diigo](https://www.diigo.com). When you bookmark a page to Diigo, you can choose to upload the page, even if it is dynamic or hidden from public view with password protection. With such services, if you updated the page on the server and wished the other person to be able to see the latest update, you would have to clip/archive the page to the service again, since the service would be storing a copy of what the page looked like at the moment you clipped/archived the page while you were viewing it from your browser.

If you need to provide the other person with CSS and JavaScript, you could provide all the external CSS and JavaScript files as separate Evernote notes, but that's probably not a good solution for you. What about saving the page via a browser? E.g., if you access the page from Internet Explorer, you can click on "File", "Save as" and then use "Webpage, complete" for "Save as type". That will create an HTM file for the page along with a directory containing the .css and .js files used on the page. Firefox also provides a similar option to save webpages as "Web Page, complete", creating an HTM file and associated directory with .css and .js files. In Chrome, Alt-F and then "Save page as" creates an .html file and associated directory with those files also, if you save as "Webpage, Complete".

You could then zip the file and its associated directory and share that zip file with the other person who could extract the contents of the zip file and open the .htm file in his/her browser to see what you are seeing and could also edit the files and send the edited files back to you.

EDIT per original poster: Per the answerer's comments:

> @user1032531, yes, the "Webpage, Complete" option saves the page as it
>   looks from the browser's perspective. You will get a .htm or .html
>   file and a directory with the same name that contains all the images,
>   .css, and .js files associated with the page placed in the directory,
>   which you can then zip yourself and send to someone else. Internet
>   Explorer (IE) also offers an option to save as "Web Archive, single
>   file (*.mht)", which IE browsers can view, but Firefox & Chrome can't
>   without an add-on, so saving as "Webpage, Complete" & zipping the file
>   and associated directory yourself may be best –  moonpoint Jan 4 at
>   5:01

Comment: Thanks moonpoint.  No, a PDF won't work.  My purpose if to given them the client side code so they could make changes to the associated JavaScript/CSS/HTML.  They will then send me back the work, and I could change the server code to reflect their changes in HTML, and replace the appropriate JS/CSS files.  I will check out Evernote.

Comment: @user1032531, since you need to provide CSS, JavaScript, and HTML for the page for the other person to edit, Evernote is probably not  the best method to provide a copy of the page and its associated files then, so I edited my comment with another alternative.

Comment: I can't zip it either since the HTML is generated using PHP.  Furthermore, the various CSS/JS files are located in various locations many directories all several levels deep.  I just need to capture what the browser sees.

Comment: @user1032531, the "save as" option from within a web browser viewing the page is capturing the code the browser is seeing at that moment. I.e., it is seeing the HTML file as generated from the PHP code. It doesn't matter where the CSS and JS files are located on your server, when you save as "Webpage, Complete", they will be saved in one directory associated with an HTML file, both of which will be created by the browser on the system viewing the page. When the other person opens the saved HTML file in his browser, the CSS and JS files in the associated directory will be used for its display.

Comment: Yes, the HTML is exact, however, the links to JS/CSS/images will not work.  That is the part I don't know how to accomplish.

Comment: @user1032531, are you saving the files from your browser as "Webpage, Complete" rather than "WebPage, HTML Only"? When I save a web page from a browser as "Webpage, Complete", what I normally see is 1 HTM file and a directory of the same name. Within the directory are all images from the page as well as the CSS and JS files. If I open the file in another browser as long as the HTML file and its associated directory are together, the page usually displays as it did in the original browser. The links in the HTM file to images, etc. have been adjusted to point to files in the associated directory

Comment: aah, no, I just view the source code.  You mean you can save the files from the browsers prospective as "Website Complete"?  Does this save it as a single file or some zip file?  Regardless, this is exactly what I wish to do.  What browser are you using?

Comment: On the website, press ctrl s to save it. Works in all browsers on Windows, and I'm sure all browsers on Linux

Comment: @user1032531, yes, the "Webpage, Complete" option saves the page as it looks from the browser's perspective. You will get a .htm or .html file and a directory with the same name that contains all the images, .css, and .js files associated with the page placed in the directory, which you can then zip yourself and send to someone else. Internet Explorer (IE) also offers an option to save as "Web Archive, single file (*.mht)", which IE browsers can view, but Firefox & Chrome can't without an add-on, so saving as "Webpage, Complete" & zipping the file and associated directory yourself may be best

Comment: `Webpage, complete` is exactly what I am looking for!  I never knew it existed.  I had vaguely recalled `mht` files and also considered them, but I think the other is a bit better.  Please feel free to update your answer.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (depending on lots of things like the type of content and setup of the server) may be to set up an area in the website which is not password protected and then symlink the protected content, using a string of random characters for the name of the symlink - this acts as a kind of low-security password.

Comment: Thanks David,  Yes, I suppose I "could" do this, but I was hoping to actually make a copy of the content.  In addition to the apache .htpasswd, the serverside application also has a password.  How do I get past this unless I sign in, render the HTML, and make a copy of it?

Comment: This question can't be answered without knowing about your coding framework etc.   CURL is an all-purpose toolbox which can probably be of assistance in scraping your site.

Comment: Yes, I could do something using CURL, but it seems to me I would need to build some application that mimics the logon credentials of the main application and sets sessions as needed.  I would have expected some client side tool exists like firebug.  You logon using the browser, cookies are set, and it takes a snapshot of the URL saving all client available HTML and resources.